# should I use 301 or 302 redirect for access control?

Tags: redirect, routes, authorization, server-side

I provide users with file/media links that are only references to the actual file. One the server side I intercept this link and check if the user has access to said file. If they do I redirect them to the final link that contains a expiriable policy for what they can do to the resource and for how long.

My question is if a 302 redirect makes more sense than a 301 and/or if there is a better way to handle this?

```
if user
    file = share.Files.findOne({_id: @params._id, accessibleBy: user._id})
    if file
      location = "/server/file/" + file._id + "/" + file.policy + "/" + file.signature
      @response.writeHead(301, {Location: location})
  @response.end()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 301 means ‘moved permanently’—if the URL is ever valid, no, it hasn’t moved permanently. A 302 (‘Found’) would be better, yes, but 303 (‘See Other’) would be even more appropriate.

Comment: It doesn't appear there could even be a better answer than 303 since it pretty much describes this exact use case. Was not aware. Thanks!